# PhpMyAdmin Switch Localhost Account

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

A few months back, I had one website hosted on `localhost`, via `WAMP`. I was able to perform everything I needed with no issues. I was able to connect to `PhpMyAdmin` via `localhost/phpmyadmin` with the default user and pass.

At that point, I started a new project, and moved the `localhost` to point to this new project. Along with this, I switched the `phpmyadmin` used to use this new project's database.

I've now tried to resume development on the original project, but anytime I go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` and log in, it's still pointing to the 2nd project. Both usernames and passwords for `localhost/phpmyadmin` are still the default `root` and empty password.

I've tried to go through the `.conf` files within wamp but have not found anything that has helped.

I can access the correct site via `localhost`, but `localhost/phpmyadmin` logs me into the wrong database.

Any help would be appreciated! I'm sure it's just one of the `.conf` files, but I'm unsure which one.

Comment: Generally we link our projects with phpmyadmin's db, but you are doing the reverse thing.

Comment: If you are talking about the connection string, then ensure that the host is correct you also provide a port too if needed.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay What confuses me as well is that localhost goes to the correct site, but localhost/phpmyadmin goes to the wrong phpmyadmin. I would think those would be directly linked in some way for that to not happen

Comment: Do you have two different xamp running ?

Comment: Nope, only 1 wamp is currently running

Comment: @Sej: ...where you say: `...moved the localhost to point to this new project`, how was this done originally? If it was a .conf file, then do you not recall the file that was modified? Or was it done some other way?

Comment: @PaulT. sadly I don't remember what I did. It was back in May, so it's been a while. I've tried looking through all of the `.conf` files to see anything that changed or look for familiar things or anything with that specific project's name, and haven't been able to find anything. I'm cxonsidering just reinstalling WAMP and then just exporting my live websites data to use on my localhost.

Comment: @Sej: ...you may be able sort the various directory contents by date to see if any files modified in May?